# Can a Kafka broker keep id but change advertised listener?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a cluster of 3 Kafka brokers. Most of the topics have replication factor of 2, while the consumer offsets all have a replication factor of 3.

I need to change where the individual brokers are listening, i.e. the IPs/hostnames on which they are listening. Is it possible to change the advertised listeners for a given broker ID? Or do I have to create a new broker with a different ID, repartition topics, and remove the old broker?

Assuming it does work, does the official Java Kafka client realize that the listener has changed and re-request the list of brokers for the topic(s)?

For the interested, I am running Kafka in Kubernetes. Originally, I needed access from both inside and outside the cluster, so I had services with `nodePort` (`hostPort` did not work with CNI prior to Kubernetes 1.7).

It worked, but was complex. I no longer need access from outside Kubernetes, so would like to keep it simple and have three brokers that advertise their hostname.

Can I bring down a broker and restart it with a different advertised listener? Or must I add a new broker, rebalance, and remove the old one?

Comment: The docs contains an example of changing listeners (in that case, to secure a cluster): https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_rolling_upgrade. (As with any larger change I think it's good to practice on a test cluster.)

Comment: I don't know how I missed this in the docs, but very helpful, thank you. Basically: 1. You can restart the same broker with different advertised listeners, and the cluster itself handles it correctly. 2. You need to bounce the clients for them to pick up the change.

Comment: @salient that was quite helpful, thank you. You should put it as an answer. Am I correct in that the consumer libraries do not auto-adjust? Once they get a list of brokers via the discovery protocol, that list is fixed? And if a broker changes its listener (e.g. IP changes), then consumers need to be restarted?